# Candle detached from ema and distance

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to develop a strategy, but i am unable to write 2 conditions. can anyone please help me?

condition 1:   Candle detached completely from 5 EMA. i mean not even the wick/shadow is touching  5 EMA.
condition 2: Number of pips  between current price level to 100 ema.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of codes should do the trick

```
emaGap = ema(close,100) > high or ema(close,100) < low

pipNum = abs(close - ema(close,100))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I will test it now :)

Comment: i am getting "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function" when i am trying to use resolution. can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: This is happening because the pipnum is constantly changing. If you want to keep it constant from the time it was made, use var pipNum. But don't forget to add this line var pipNum = na after you have exited the position. If you don't add this line, the pine script will remember the original number and use it in all cases

Comment: Thanks again, I will test it